# Where can I find furniture screws that lock into embedded metal parts?

Tags: screws, furniture, hardware

I'm renovating an old box for the MRS. as a bit of a project. It's missing some parts which appear to be the type of screws you get in "flat pack" furniture whereby you screw so much into the wood, it then slots into another piece and you add a metal object that you rotate to lock it all in place.

I basically need to find some replacements and I have one taken out. I just don't know what its called and what length I need.

Anybody in the know able to assist me?

Comment: Can you provide a picture?

Comment: You can often use a different method to secure wood that was previously connected with cam-lock fasteners. The mfgr. uses those because they are simple/intuitive and require no drilling by the end-user. You can probably use regular wood screws (even better with glue) if you can drill pilot holes.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it, that also would make a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Do an image search for "cam lock fastener". You'll find what you need.

Comment: There's a reasonable likelihood that you'll be able to find them at IKEA. Probably available at other on-line sources, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can often use a different method to secure wood that was previously connected with cam-lock fasteners. The mfgr. uses those because they are simple/intuitive and require no drilling by the end-user. You can probably use regular wood screws (even better with glue) if you can drill pilot holes.